# Creating load for app engine testing

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm implementing a tool to generate data and load for our app engine based application. The requirement is to post data to an endpoint.

I implemented initial python version based on solution presented in [Google's load testing article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/load_test) and I'm currently running the script on compute engine virtual machine. At this point I have been able to get ~1800 requests / second using 50 threads when posting to an empty endpoint. It seems that increasing threads beyond 50 doesn't increase request / second rate.

Currently in order to create more requests / second, I'm creating more compute engine instances and running the script simultaneously from multiple virtual machines.

My question is that is there a better way for this. What is the recommended or optimal way to achieve this?